# Let $K$ be a number field, and $R$ a $\overline{K}$-algebra, equipped with a continuous action of $G_K$. Is $R$ defined over $K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a number field, and $R$ a $\overline{K}$-algebra, so we are given an inclusion $i : \overline{K}\hookrightarrow R$. Suppose there is an action of $G_K = \text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on $R$ satisfying:

1. The stabilizer of any $r\in R$ has finite index (ie, the action is *continuous* when $R$ is given the discrete topology, and
2. For $\sigma\in G_K$, $\sigma\circ i = i\circ\sigma$.

Then must there exist a $K$-subalgebra $R_K\subset R$ on which $G_K$ acts as the identity, and such that $R \cong R_K\otimes_K \overline{K}$?

Comment: The keyword to look up here is "Galois descent." See here for starters: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf